# Online edition of Kuntres Tiferes Dovid

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, mussar-ethics

In the recently published sefer, [Bircas HaTorah, Bringing Torah To Life And Life To Torah](https://www.feldheim.com/bircas-hatorah-bringing-torah-to-life-and-life-to-torah) by [Rabbi Nissim Tagger](https://www.bircas.org/rabbi-nissim-tagger/), a Kuntres is cited. It seems to be a Kuntres by Rabbi Dovid Leibowitz ztz"l, a great-nephew of the Chofetz Chaim, amd rosh yeshivah of the Chofetz Chaim Yeshivah in America (p, 13).

The kuntres is called: **Kuntres Tiferes Dovid**. And I am specifically looking for *perek 5, sv VeAl ken lo hayah*.

Does anyone know:

- What this kuntres is about?
- By whom the kuntres is written?
- Where to find chapter 5 from this kuntres online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as your first two points see [here](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990040567050205171/NLI)

The blurb there writes:

> קונטרס תפארת דוד : בעניני דרכי לימוד התורה ותלמודה לרבים / מביא ממאמריו ומדרכיו של רבי חיים דוד הכהן לייבאוויטש
> עם הרחבת הדיבור והביאור מושרש ומיוסד על הנשמע והמקובל מאת בנו, רבי אלתר חנוך הענאך הכהן לייבאוויטש ועל פי הנשמע עוד מאת תלמידי הגרח"ד הכהן
> נכתב ע"י יהודה אריה ליב שמידמאן
> ונתוסף כאן עוד חידושים במסכת שבת מאת רבי חיים דוד הכהן שנתחדשו ונכתבו על ידו בלימודו בחבורת בית-המדרש בית ישראל דסלבודקה-קובנה ויצאו לאור בס' כתבי בית ישראל ע"י רבי יצחק אייזיק שר.
>
> Kuntres Tiferes Dovid: Regarding the ways of learning the Torah and Talmud for many / it brings from the articles and ways of [Rabbi Chaim Dovid HaCohen Leibowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovid_Leibowitz) with the expansion of speech and commentary rooted and based on what is heard and accepted by his son, [Rabbi Alter Chanoch Henoch HaCohen Leibowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henoch_Leibowitz), and what was heard from the students of HaGaon Rav Chaim Dovid HaCohen written by Yehuda Aryeh Leib Shmidman, and adds further chiddushim here in Masechta Shabbos by Rabbi Chaim Dovid HaCohen that was updated and written by him during his studies in the chaburos in Beis Midrash Beis Yisroel of Slabodka-Kovno, published in the sefer Kisvei Beis Yisroel* by [Rabbi Yitzchok Isaac Sher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Isaac_Sher).

---

*All three volumes available on Hebrewbooks - [Vol 1.](https://hebrewbooks.org/40942), [Vol.2](https://hebrewbooks.org/40943) & [Vol. 3](https://hebrewbooks.org/40944)

Comment: Wonderful, many thanks Dov. Do you also know where to find perek 5, sv VeAl ken lo hayah?

Comment: @Shmuel - I looked on hebrewbooks and otzar it doesn't seem available on those websites but if you look at the National Library of Israel link I shared it tells you where you can locate hard copies...